# Getting XMLHttpRequest failed error in parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to submit data in parse via javascript. But upon sumbit button click I am getting the following error :

> `User Query Error :XMLHttpRequest failed: {}`

Below is my code :

```
user.signUp(null, {
                success: function(user){
                    alert("Successfully signed up !")

                    //Copy the Object ID generated for the user to the UserId field in the profile table.

                    var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
                    var user = new User();

                    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(User);
                    userQuery.find({
                        success: function(results)
                        {
                            for (var i in results) 
                            {
                                //Comparing the username from the User table to the typed username and obtaining
                                //the corresponding objectId.
                                if(results[i].get("username")==userName) 
                                {
                                    var objectId = results[i].get("objectId");
                                    console.log("ObjectId : "+objectId);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    console.log("No such user.")
                                }
                            }
                        } ,error: function(error)
                            {
                                console.log("User Query Error :"+error.message);
                            }
                    });
                    window.location.href = "index.html";

                    } , error: function(user, error){
                        console.log("signup error:"+error.message);
                        alert(" Error in sign up");                     }
                    });
```

I am not able to figure out the exact problem. Can anyone help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Go the answer myself. I had the same name variables. All I did was change 2 lines.

```
var myUser = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(myUser);
                    userQuery.find({
```

It ran like a charm.